# How do I tweak default parameters using forest.robu? e.g. move the vertical reference line to zero, change decimal points for effect sizes to 2,

Tags: r

I have managed to create a forest plot of my intercept-only output using robu in R. I used the forest.robu documentation to do this. However, the functions are limited to default settings and I was wondering what I need to add to the code to change a few things e.g. :

- move the dotted reference line to zero (not the summary effect size)
- change the effect sizes listed to 2 not 3 decimal places
- Add lb and ub CIs from the output, to list next to the individual study effect sizes.

I have looked at the source code but with limited coding experience, I am unsure as to what exactly I need to add to make these changes.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Lucy.

I used the forest.robu documentation to create the default-style forest plot. I tried adding to the forest.robu function list things like abline=0 but this didn't work.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Explicitly list all non-base R packages you are using in the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.